# How to reply to a recruiter ‘thanks for reaching out, I'd like to hear more’?

Tags: translation

A recruiter wrote me over Linkedin and I'd like to ask for more details, but my Chinese is completely rusty. Linkedin's predefined answer is "您好，感谢与我联系！我希望了解更多信息。". I would like to use another one, if there is any suitable, plus this one sounds a bit too 'canned'.

How about "您好，谢谢你发给我的消息，请你解释一下"？

Comment: The downside of expressing it well is that if you get the job and then they realize that you are not as fluent as they had thought …

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps better not to mix up 您 and 你. Stay with one of them.

First part is ok. "您好，谢谢您发给我的消息，

My suggestion for the second part is:

Could you please give me more details?
您是否能够给我更多的详细信息？

Answer (score 1):

> thanks for reaching out,
>
> "您好，谢谢您发给我的消息"

消息 mainly means "news" you should write " 來函 (formal term for " the letter you sent" or 來訊 (formal term for "the message you sent")

A formal reply:

"**谢谢您的來訊**"

> I'd like to hear more
>
> 请你解释一下"

解释 mainly means " explain"

To reply formally, you can write

"还望告知详情" (Please tell me the details/ Please tell me more)

Since it is about the details of a job, you should add the topic "this job"  in your reply

"**还望告知此职位之详情**" (Please tell me the details of this job/ Please tell me more about this job)

More modern wording: "**谢谢您的來訊, 请告欣我有关这职位的更多详情**"

Answer (score 0):

Out of ambiguity, you'd better tell what kind of details you want to know from them. It can be something like: 你好，感谢与我联系！能把这职位的详细信息发给我看一下吗？ or 我想了解一下这个职位的详细信息。